Older woman disrobes in front of a boy while he eats an apple
Searching for a live action film from the 1980s about an old man reliving the memories of his youth.  I believe the world "love" is present in the title.  I think the dialogue was in English, but I don't recall for certain.  
In one scene in that I remember in particular, an older woman removes her gown in front of a boy who's eating an apple, touches him and tries to seduce him. An older man is watching.  This woman hides on the terrace when another woman (probably the boy's mother) enters. The second woman is crying. The nude woman returns, puts on her gown, flashes the boy and leaves.
There are other scenes where the old man (while in his youth) peeps on a couple having sex.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it about? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes, recognisable actors or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

The movie you are lookin for is * Amor Estranho Amor *. It's a 1982 Brazilian erotic drama film.

Here's your forbidden Apple !
